# FIWARE context broker storing all data to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, fiware, broker

I have installed fiware context broker and I am sending data to it using the  localhost:1026/v1/updateContext end point.

Everything is working properly and I am able to get and visualise the data being sent. As orion is a broker service the latest only entity can be received.

Question: I need to save automatically the historical data to a mongo db database. Orion save only the latest 2 entries. STH and Cygnus is not doing the job since they require a lot of configuration both in sending data and collecting, storing etc.

Is there anyway to automatically save all data being sent to orion? And group them by service ids?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 
Playing around with context broker, I altered the way that orion stores the data to the auto generated mongodb. When one send data to the orion the id of the json will be always the servicepath, the id of the json and the type. Therefore new data gets overwritten. We need to change that by having another element in the id that is incremental therefore new entries are saved. I am not sure if this is a clumsy solution but is definitely more scalable since we don't need subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the only way to store historical data in FIWARE is through STH, QuantumLeap (incubated GE) or Cygnus.

Configuring them is not so difficult. Please follow these tutorials:

https://github.com/Fiware/tutorials.Historic-Context

https://github.com/Fiware/tutorials.Time-Series-Data

https://github.com/Fiware/tutorials.Short-Term-History

http://fiwaretourguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generating-historical-context-information-sth-comet/how-to-generate-the-history-of-Context-Information-using-STH-Comet/

http://fiwaretourguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storing-data-cygnus-mysql/how-to-store-data-cygnus-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

Precisely, orchestrating the persistence of historical data of context entities is the purpose of CYGNUS Generic Enabler. Then you can use STH to store historical data for the most recent period of time or choose some other alternative such as [Cosmos](https://catalogue-server.fiware.org/enablers/bigdata-analysis-cosmos) for Big Data.

You can find in the official [documentation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_sth_sink.md) of cygnus, examples of configuration files in order to persist data for STH. In addition, if you are familiar with MongoDB,  [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_mongo_sink.md) is official documentation of the Mongodb Sink, with examples for the different persistence configurations.

If you give me a little more information about how you are configuring Cygnus and STH I could help you more.

Regards!

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I have installed Cygnus and STH and they are running as expected. The issue is that for persistent data there is the requirement of subscription. For example for every service we need to subscribe to get persistent data. This is not very scalable especially if you do not have a platform administrator. Ideally what I would like is to have a persistent mongodb or collection that is aligned with a fiware-service, therefore the data received by orion is being automatically stored. Hope this is possible.